# How to run django project without virtual environment

Tags: django

I'v downloaded django project which I need to modify.

But there is no such thing as virtualenv, and I have always launched by `python manage.py runserver` which is only possible after `source virtualenvname/bin/acivate`

the structure is the following:

```
project
project.sql
manage.py
requirments.txt
```

How do I run it with this structure ? I just need to modify it as it is

Comment: So why don't you make a virtualenv?

Comment: @DanielRoseman  I was just interested whether it's possible to run without it? Because it was a task project which was originally without any virtualenv

Comment: Of course it's possible. But I highly doubt it was "originally without any virtualenv"; requirements.txt is almost always used in conjunction with a virtualenv. Presumably they're just expecting you to create one when you download it, which would be the normal practice.

Answer (score 5):

1. If are willing to overwrite your global packages with current project requirement then:

   ```
   sudo pip install -r requirements.txt
   ```
2. Apply db migrations:

   ```
   python manage.py migrate
   ```
3. Run the dev server

   ```
   python manage.py runserver
   ```